# Selenium c# Ilist Iweb Element not getting the text of all elements

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

im using IList to get a list of elements and the text value to be able to click on the correct element

```
IList<IWebElement> PONumbers = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("first-column"));
        
        int POCount = PONumbers.Count;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < POCount; i++)
        { 
            String PONo = PONumbers.ElementAt(i).Text;
            
            if (PONo.Equals(PONoNonBatchNonTonne))
            {
                PONumbers.ElementAt(i).Click();
                break;
            }
        }
```

It gets all the correct elements which is 36

It only gets the text for the first 8 elements and then the rest are showing as ""

this is the html code:
[image: this is the html code]

it seems to be only getting the text of the elements in the view, but then why would it get all elements

any help welcome?

Comment: Are you sure that the text is not inserted by the script? If this is the case, then try scrolling through the list and see if new text appears in this case.

Comment: The element might hidden on web page. Try with textContent attribute. Instead String `PONo = PONumbers.ElementAt(i).Text` try with `String PONo = PONumbers.ElementAt(i).GetAttribute("textContent");`

Comment: @KunduK thanks this now got the text but when it clicks on the element i get element not interactable, think im going to have to use the scroll somehow

Comment: @JadeLaird : You can either scroll or use javascript executor to click on the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the element is hidden on webpage you have to use `textContent` attribute to get the value. To click on the element either scroll the page or use javaScript executor to click on the specific element.

```
IList<IWebElement> PONumbers = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("first-column"));
        
        int POCount = PONumbers.Count;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < POCount; i++)
        { 
            String PONo = PONumbers.ElementAt(i).GetAttribute("textContent");
            
            if (PONo.Equals(PONoNonBatchNonTonne))
            {
                IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
                executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", PONumbers.ElementAt(i));                
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium only gets the elements that are in the view.

Once you have the last element you should be able to select it, send it some keys another 8 times, arrow down usually,and get the next 8 elements.

This would be have to be done for each set of 8 until you get the last one.

The web is loading content dynamically through jsp or similar and selenium needs to manually access all of the content that is dynamically loaded.

In order to test my theory run your test and go back to the browser window, select the last element in the view and see which key selects the next element and moves the elements in the view.

Comment: yes the table is scrollable so if i scroll down it gets the text of the other elements.

Comment: The most basic answer would be to scroll through the page and get the ones in view 8 at a time forcing a scroll on the 8th one to get the next 8 and so forth. I get it is not the fastest solution  but it would be the simplest. It is either that or positioning the mouse at some coordinates and clicking on the lowest element in view by guesstimating the position if clicking on the lowest one scrolls the table, happens in some pages with dynamic elements.